# Remove Header and Footer if user is not logged on

Tags: hooks

Using Hook, is there a way to remove the Header and Footer from the specific page that is trying to access by users, if the current user is not logged on?

```
function footer_header_remove() {
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page('the-page')){
       //Remove Header and Footer of "the-page"
    }
}
add_action('???????????', 'footer_header_remove');
```

Comment: Do you have a page template for that page or?

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of ways to do this.

The first important thing is next: You must have a header or a footer (default header and footer, from WP) if you want to have functionality.

E.g If you are loaded scripts or styles in `function.php` they will be broken, because you can't load them without header or footer.

[You can create more types of footers or headers](https://www.webascender.com/blog/how-to-create-multiple-headers-footers-in-wordpress/) where if you have one page or one type of page templates you can do that on this way:

```
// your example-template.php
    
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
    get_header('blank-header');
}
```

And for the footer do the same thing.

In your case, where you want to load or not header and footer from the function, you can use `'init'` hook or you can use the last hook before loading the template is `'template_redirect'` that is your choice.